# Why is the centre of mass displaced even when external force is 0?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> A pulley fixed to a rigid support carries a rope whose one end is tied to a ladder and a man and the other end to the counterweight of mass $M$. The man of mass $m$ climbs up a distance of $h$ with respect to the ladder and then stops. If the mass of the rope and the friction in the pulley axle are negligible find the displacement of the center of mass of the system.

My question is that the net external force on the system is 0 then why is there any displacement of centre of mass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a net force on the system of the mass and the man in the form of the normal force provided by the pulley on the string. Similar questions have already been asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/58193/movement-of-man-and-ladder-and-their-center-of-mass), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102760/man-on-a-rope-task) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245160/laws-of-motion-while-climbing-a-rope).

Comment: what is the effect of that normal force on the displacement of centre of mass. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ritu Khanna: I believe that it has already been mentioned very clearly in the linked posts in my answer.

Comment: I have already gone through the links but can't see anywhere about normal force of pulley. Yes there is a mention of work done by pulley somewhere in link no 1 but it's not clear

Comment: @Ritu Khanna: "Just for clarity's sake, I'll point out that the pulley does work on the entire system in that the center of mass moves up and the force that sustains it is provided by the pulley. Of course, it's a frictionless pulley, so it's not doing any work rotationally, just vertically." What else are you not clear about?

Comment: Before the man started the move, the pulley still applied the normal force but then the centre of mass was stationary. I simply cant understand why the normal force applied by pulley on the string causes displacement in centre of mass

Comment: @Ritu Khanna: Consider our system to be the mass and the man connected by the string. The external forces are gravity and the normal force, which act all the time. However, if the man exerts a force on the string, the normal force increases, but gravity doesn't. That's why the net force on the system is now upwards and the center of mass moves upwards accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I get ut now. It was very generous of you to patiently answer my query. Thanks

Comment: a late comment: But what if we consider the pulley+string+mass :the force provides by pulley  is internal,the string provides a tension which is internal the net gravitational force on the two masses is zero then where is the external force ,i am making a mistake somewhere ament i?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore The tension is not internal and "net gravitational force on the two masses" is not zero.

Comment: @VincentThacker since the two masses are of equal weight the net force is zero,and since the tension is exerted by a component present in the system the force is internal

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore No. The net gravity is the sum of the two masses times $g$. If you consider the entire system, then the person is exerting a force on the support of the pulley and thus the Earth. The center of mass in inertial space remains constant but the Earth has moved slightly downward and the center of mass of the two masses has moved upwards.